# Changing the root site of python-eve

Tags: python, flask, eve

I'm currently making a API using python-eve, and I've set it up with eve-swagger on `/api-docs` and flask_swagger_ui on `/docs`.

What I want to do and haven't been able is to find a way is to replace `/` with the swagger_ui (`/docs`)

Comment: How are you serving your application? Isn't this redirect done in the web server configuration?

Comment: I'm still on the prototyping stage. But I was planning on using eve with gunicorn/nginx in front. But I guess I can use Nginx with a permanent redirect instead of changing it in eve.

Comment: I believe that's the way to go @Lars.